# How to correctly display in class data from joined sql tables?

Tags: mysql, jdbc

I've started to learn SQL, I'd appreciate some insight and help on the below issue. My task is to: write a query in SQL workbench which returns names and surnames of users with more than 2 posts written (the query copied below). This part seems to work fine.

Then display in test class in a loop names and surnames of users that have published at least 2 posts.
How to write a code that creates that query in the test class? Basically I get syntax error and I'm not sure how it should look like("Column 'POSTS_NUMBERS' not found.").

(then another part of exercise follows - add posts and then check by assertion if the actual number of records in the data base is the same as result of the query)

```sql
SELECT USERS.FIRSTNAME, USERS.LASTNAME, USERS.ID, COUNT(*) AS POSTS_NUMBER
FROM USERS 
JOIN POSTS ON USERS.ID = POSTS.USER_ID
GROUP BY POSTS.USER_ID
HAVING COUNT(*) >= 2;
```

```java
@Test
public void testSelectUsersAndPosts() throws SQLException {
    //given
    DbManager dbManager = DbManager.getInstance();
    String countQuery = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM USERS";             //IS THIS PART CORRECT?
    Statement statement = dbManager.getConnection().createStatement();
    ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery(countQuery);
    int count = 0;
    while (rs.next()) {
        System.out.println(rs.getInt("POSTS_NUMBERS") + ", " +
                rs.getString("FIRSTNAME") + ", " +
                        rs.getString("LASTNAME"));
    }
    String sql = "INSERT INTO POSTS(USER_ID, BODY) VALUES ('3', 'I am Mark')";
    statement.executeUpdate(sql);
    sql = "INSERT INTO POSTS(USER_ID, BODY) VALUES ('3', 'hey!')";
    statement.executeUpdate(sql);

    //when
    String sqlQuery = "SELECT * FROM USERS";
    statement = dbManager.getConnection().createStatement();
    rs = statement.executeQuery(sqlQuery);

    //then
    int counter = 0;
    while (rs.next()) {
        System.out.println(rs.getInt("USERS.ID") + ", " +
                rs.getString("FIRSTNAME") + ", " +
                rs.getString("LASTNAME"));
        counter++;

    int expected = count + 1;
    Assert.assertEquals(expected, counter);

    rs.close();
    statement.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: The query you use in your Java code, `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM USERS`, does not have a column called `POSTS_NUMBERS` (nor `FIRSTNAME` or `LASTNAME`), so of course `rs.getInt("POSTS_NUMBERS")` will fail.

Comment: Ok, maybe it seems to be a stupid question but when I write "SELECT USERS.FIRSTNAME, USERS.LASTNAME, POSTS_NUMBER FROM USERS", then still I am getting error - unknown column "post numbers" in field list.  I don't fully get it. I know that in USERS table I do not have field "post_numbers", but I  joined the tables...so how the syntax should look like?

Comment: Your table `USERS` doesn't have a column `POSTS_NUMBERS`, look at your SQL query that you claim works MySQL Workbench: it doesn't have a table column `POSTS_NUMBER`, instead it has an **expression** (`COUNT(*)`), and gives that an alias `POSTS_NUMBER`, in other words it is a column that only exists inside that select not in any table.

Comment: Ok, I get it, thanks